# Reading file, line by line, character by character in C

Tags: c, file, io

I have a problem with reading a file in C.
I want to read a file line by line.
Each line contains 25 characters and each character has a special value that I    have to use in other functions. My code:

```
int read_file(const char* filename){

    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
    char line[25];
    int i;
    int counter = 0;



    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
    {
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {

                for(i = 0; i < 25 ; i++){
                     printf("%s",line[i]);
                }
        }
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

I have to do something else then print it, but when I try this code, it gives errors, so doing something else would do the same I guess.
So my code needs to read the file line by line and then I need to be able to read it character by character.

Comment: check the return value of `fopen()` first.

Comment: this line: `char line[25];` is not large enough for a 25 char line to be input.  it needs more room for the newline and more room for the trailing NUL byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- An array of 25 elements isn't enough to store lines of 25 characters: +1 for newline and +1 for terminating null character.
- You should check if the opening of the file is successful
- `%c` have to be used to print one character via `printf`.

fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int read_file(const char* filename){

    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
    char line[27]; /* an array of 25 elements isn't enough to store lines of 25 characters: +1 for newline and +1 for terminating null character */
    int i;
    int counter = 0;

    if (file == NULL) return 1; /* check if the file is successfully opened */

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
    {
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {

            for(i = 0; i < 25 ; i++){
                 printf("%c",line[i]); /* use %c instead of %s to print one character */
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 printf("%s",line[i]);     // %s expects char * and line[i] is  a char
```

This should be -

```
 printf("%c",line[i]);     // to print character by charcter
```

To store `25` characters declare `line` as -

```
char line[25+1];  // +1 for null character
```

*Note* - As you ask in comment to `%s` can be used as -

```
printf("%s",line);         // no loop required
```

Comment: And when do you use %s?

Comment: `%s` is useful to print **a sttring**. example: `printf("%s", line);`

Comment: @fangio  When you want to print **C-style string**  .  C-style string is _null terminated character array_ .

Comment: Is it normal that printing the full line at once gives another result than printing one by one?

Comment: @fangio  Just for output no (Maybe each character in different line if you use `'\n'` ), other than  that printing character by character  requires an extra loop .